# Qt pass data between multiple forms

Tags: qt

I am new to Qt and understands the concept of signal and slots. However I am not able to implement it.

My objective is:

Form1 has a button Config. So when I click Config it should open another form Form2( without closing Form1) and send a string strData to Form2.

In Form2 I set some value in the string strData. Then I click Ok button in Form2, Form2 should close and return back the string to Form1.

When the call returns back to Form1, it should continue from where it emitted the signal to invoke Form2.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this using signals/slots; the signal is emitted, and all of the connected slots are executed, and then the code continues from where the signal is emitted and eventually returns to the event loop. That's when your second form is actually shown and the user can respond to it, but by then, your code is long past where the signal was emitted.

What I believe you're looking for is the QDialog::exec method; use it in place of the signal. The basic pattern of the code is:

```
// This is the response to click on Config...
Form2Dialog form2;
form2.setSomeStringValue (some_value);

if (form2.exec() == QDialog::Accepted)
{
    QString some_new_value = form2.newValue();
}
```

The Form2Dialog is a subclass of QDialog where you've added your own setSomeStringValue and newValue methods. (What you actually name these is up to you.)

The important thing is that the exec method blocks and doesn't return until the user selects OK or Cancel on the dialog, or closes it using the "close" button in the title bar (if there is one).